# Mat Paginator didn't show pages numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using Angular to display a tabulated page. On this page, I intend to display records and implement pagination. However, the pagination page numbers are not being displayed As shown in the image.
[pagination image wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsa18.png)

exemple code link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/customize-mat-paginator?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fpolyfills.ts,src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fapp%2FpaginatorStyleDirective.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css
any one help me to diplay this list

image wanted [pagination with pages numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikBZR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `BrowserAnimationsModule` to `app.module.ts`. There were console errors that caused the UI not to be displayed!

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './material-module';
import { StylePaginatorDirective } from './paginatorStyleDirective';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; // <- changed here

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule, // <- changed here
    FormsModule,
    MaterialModule,
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, StylePaginatorDirective],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/customize-mat-paginator-ijjrge?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fpolyfills.ts,src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fapp%2FpaginatorStyleDirective.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmaterial-module.ts)

Comment: "I have already imported BrowserAnimationsModule.

Comment: @contact in your stackblitz it was missing, after that it started working, plz check my stackblitz, that is the expected output right?

Comment: thanks Naren Murali @contact i want to add pages numbers to mat-paginator any help please

Comment: @contact please give more details, what is missing in the stackblitz, give clear idea what you are expecting, if possible a screenshot highlighting the issue in the stackblitz output!